# Should i use public/private key encryption in this case?

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone app and a backend php web app.

The php site stores some information and i have to use the iPhone app to retrieve that data and show it in it.

So, suppose the iphone app has to show a list of houses for a given user, it would call the folllowing php script

http://example/process.php?user=300

That script makes the sql query and returns an xml with the houses' data.

Should i at any point encrypt anything to prevent spoofing?

Another case, for example admob for each app generates a "publisher id" that is used in the iphone app to "connect" the app with the web app, is that "publisher id" used as a private key to encrypt/decrypt the data sent/received?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does the user have to authenticate? If so, it would be better to generate a token on the server after the authentication step, and use that token in subsequent webservice calls.

e.g.:

http://example/login.php?login=xxx&pw=yyyy

=> returns token **80a8b97c0c8941e1b290bdf33f3124de**  if successful

Then instead of passing a user id, pass the token:

http://example/process.php?token=80a8b97c0c8941e1b290bdf33f3124de

Comment: No, he doesn't. Imagine something like an ad network.
The developer has an app, this has an alphanumerical key.
the iphone app that wants to retrieve that has this key, so it surely retrieves the data using that.

Now, do you think that that key is also used to encrypt/decrypt the data?